# Swift: restrict generic type to closure

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

How can I restrict generic type to closures?
Like this:

```
struct Closure<T where T:closure> {
  var closure:T
  init(_ c:T) { closure = c }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think you can – instead, use generic placeholders to constrain the input and return arguments of the closure, which amounts to the same thing:

```
struct Closure<T,U> {
    var closure: T->U
    init(_ c: T->U) { closure = c }
}

let c = Closure { $0 % 2 == 0 }
// c will be a Closure<Int,Bool>
```